# How do you implement a _proper_ thread-safe server?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Imagine an application that launches the server in a separate thread. At some point later in time the server will receive a stop command from another thread.

The first problem that I see with this implementation is that the **whole** Server.stop() method is synchronized. The official Java documentation says "Invoking other objects' methods from synchronized code can create problems [with] liveness" (source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

The second problem is in my opinion that the moment thread-2 calls the Server.stop() method thread-1 (the server) could be at the ServerSocket.accept() method. That means the ServerSocket is accessed by two threads at the same time.

Can these problems actually cause issues or is the server code below totally fine?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String...args){     
        // Thread-1 = server thread
        Server server = new Server(1337);
        new Thread(server).start();

        // Thread-2 = any class stopping the server at some point
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                }
                // Call to questionable method
                server.stop();
            }           
        }).start();
    }
}

class Server implements Runnable {

    protected int port;
    protected ServerSocket serverSocket;
    protected boolean running;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        this.serverSocket = null;
        this.running = true;
    }

    public void run() { 
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Server can not be started. " + e.getMessage());
        }

        while (this.isRunning()) {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                // 2. Server thread at blocking accept method
                socket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (!this.isRunning()) {
                    System.out.println("Server stopped.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Do something with the socket 
            System.out.println("Client connected: " + socket.getInetAddress());
        }   
        System.out.println("Server terminated.");
    }

    private synchronized boolean isRunning() {
        return this.running;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (running) {
            this.running = false;
            try {
                // 1. Nested synchronized method call
                this.serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error closing server socket.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Server is already stopped.");
        }
    }

}
```

The server code is based on: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html

Answer (score 0):

> "Invoking other objects' methods from synchronized code can create problems [with] liveness"

They're warning you that when you write code in which a thread can lock more than one lock at a time, then you are risking deadlock if you don't have a plan.

The classic deadlock scenario involves two threads, A and B, and two locks 1 and 2.

```
called_in_thread_A() {
    synchronized(lock1) {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}

called_in_thread_B() {
    synchronized(lock2) {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

If these methods are called at the same time Thread A could obtain lock 1 while thread B simultaneously obtains lock 2.  At that point, neither thread will be able to get past the second lock as long as the other thread holds it, and neither thread will release the lock it holds until it gets past the second lock.  Neither thread will ever make any more progress.

In this example, the problem is obvious, but in a large, complex program, the potential for deadlock is not as easy to see.  There are strategies for *avoiding* deadlocks, and strategies for *detecting* deadlocks, and in some frameworks, strategies for *breaking* deadlocks.

If you don't employ any of those strategies in a large complex program where threads lock more than one lock at a time, then your program is at risk for deadlock.

---

One strategy for your server program would be to have the synchronized method queue up a task for a worker thread to perform.  (e.g., like using the Swing framework's `invokeLater(Runnable r)` method.)   The worker thread could then safely call the `synchronized` method of the other object.

Answer (score 0):

> The second problem is in my opinion that the moment thread-2 calls the Server.stop() method thread-1 (the server) could be at the ServerSocket.accept() method. That means the ServerSocket is accessed by two threads at the same time.

After further investigation of the Java API I found out that this is exactly how a ServerSocket is supposed to work.

> Closes this socket. Any thread currently blocked in accept() will throw a SocketException.
>
> If this socket has an associated channel then the channel is closed as well.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close--